# joomla modules is showing on every pages with associated with them

Tags: templates, caching, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I am working on Joomla from last 6 yrs. I never get any problems with Joomla. This is the 1st time i am facing Problem with it.

I made a website 
http://seoinlowcost.com/test/ I am not using module on every page but it's showing on all the pages. But when i see my website on proxy server. It's showing everything is fine.

Don't know why i am getting this problem. I have change my hosting and domain too.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's due to the Ajax request you are using. Currently when you click on a working menu item, it uses Ajax to prevent the page from refreshing and loads the component. However, I don't think the Ajax is taking the modules into consideration, therefore is not detecting what page the are and aren't supposed to be loaded on.

I would suggest disabling whatever Ajax request you're using to load the component.

On a side note, you may want to look at the hefty amount of CSS and JS files you're importing on your page, not to mention jQuery is being imported 5-6 times, therefore you're prone to conflicts.